# Gtk#: ListStore of object to ComboBoxEntry

Tags: c#, combobox, mono, cross-platform, gtk#

I have class of datastore with some fields (field1, field2, etc for example) and I want to display List of this class in ComboBoxEntry. I create extension method for IEnumerable:

```
public static ListStore ToListStore<T>(this IEnumerable<T> Parent)
        {
            ListStore returnedValue = new ListStore(typeof (object));
            //ListStore returnedValue = new ListStore (typeof(string));

            if (Parent != null) 
            {
                foreach (T node in Parent) 
                {
                    returnedValue.AppendValues (node);
                    //next two lines is just for testing.
                    TreeIter hello;
                    bool res = returnedValue.GetIterFirst (out hello);
                }
            }

            return returnedValue;
        }
```

and I fill ComboBoxEntry by the next way:

```
public static void SetGenericModel<T>(this ComboBox Parent, IEnumerable<T> Model, CellLayoutDataFunc LayoutFuncForModel)
        {
            ListStore store = Model.ToListStore ();
            /*ListStore store = new ListStore (typeof(string));
            store.AppendValues("a");
            store.AppendValues("b");*/

            CellRendererText genericClassCell = new CellRendererText();
            //Parent.Clear ();
            Parent.PackStart(genericClassCell, true);
            Parent.SetCellDataFunc(genericClassCell, LayoutFuncForModel);
            TreeIter treeIter;
            store.GetIterFirst (out treeIter);
            Parent.Model = store;

            /*int columnsCount = Parent.Model.NColumns;

            Parent.Model.GetIterFirst (out treeIter);
            object obj = Parent.Model.GetValue (treeIter, columnsCount - 1);
            Parent.Clear ();*/
        }
```

Ok, output is work fine, but when I trying to select some item of ComboBoxEntry, my application is crashed without some exceptions only output window contains some info: *"(MyAppName:14822): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: unable to set property 'text' of type 'gchararray' from value of type 'GtkSharpValue'"*. But if I create ListStore as string (commented code):

```
ListStore store = new ListStore (typeof(string));
                store.AppendValues("a");
                store.AppendValues("b");
```

then always work great.
What's wrong with my code and how can I fix this problem (I should fill ComboBoxEntry by my object, because when user select some item, I should process it as item of datastore)?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that ComboboxEntry always expects the first column to be text by default. Maybe this can be overriden by some trick. But it seems logical that a text Entry expects the value to be text, not an icon or anything else...

Now, I know that Combobox (the base class), has the first column as text by default. This line of code you commented out:

```
Parent.Clear ();
```

let you clear out any default setting and pack your own renderer.

Next step is when you want to read the content of the Combobox, you have to retrieve the value with a TreeIter, like that:

```
TreeIter iter;

if (Combo.GetActiveIter(out iter))
{
    var value = (YourClass)this.Combo.Model.GetValue(iter, 0);
}
```